# Bootstrap Style broken with autocomplete widget

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am working in a project with codeigniter and bootstrap, I made an autocomplete system, but the css looks broken like this

https://gyazo.com/4af7ae2bbdfd5547233d192b80ef947e

There is no custom style, only the bootstrap min css, here is my view html code, any help to look like it should be would be appreciated

```
<h2>Welcome to Crossover Laboratory</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1">
&nbsp;
</div>
<div class='col-md-10 text-center'>
<h3>Patients</h3>
    <?php echo $error2; ?>
    <?php 
    $attributes2 = array(
    "class"=>"form-horizontal", 
    "id" => "LoginForm2",
    "name" => "LoginForm2",
    "method" => "post"
    ); 
    echo form_open("laboratory/patients", $attributes2); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="username_patients" id="username_patients" class="ui-autocomplete-input" value="" required placeholder="Name" />
    <p id="patient_name"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

    <input type="password" name="password_patients" id="password_patients" value="" required placeholder="Code"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_submit("Login2","Login"); ?>    
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div>


<div class="col-md-1">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#username_patients").autocomplete({
        source: '<?php echo site_url('laboratory/autocomplete'); ?>',
        minlenght: 2,
        html: true,
        open: function(event, ui) 
        {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index",1000);  
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: add some css to .ui-autocomplete class or use https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js

Comment: @Gopal How can I add some CSS, I am not frontender, and how would be to use the typeahead.js??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have missed the jQueryUI CSS references. Add the below CSS in your application **`<head>`** section and try..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```